# Easy WordPress theme creation tutorial?

Tags: theme-development

I've been looking for a truly simple wordpress theme creation tutorial and haven't been able to find one. I'm specifically looking for something with sample code, a basic introduction to the syntax, and a list of all the wordpress-specific functions and variables and what they are.

Answer (score 2):

This is is good. 
http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

I would also recommend youtube, vimeo and lynda.com for video tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Codex has plenty of relevant information, but it takes some effort to find it and put together.

For starters see:

- [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [WordPress Lessons > Designing Your WordPress Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Lessons)
- [Site Design and Layout](http://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_Design_and_Layout)